# xfce4-panel and Xorg using 100% CPU when the panel Background set to 'None (use system style)'

Tags: xorg, xfce, theme

When, I use some specific themes like the Vimix theme, xfce4 and xorg combined are using more than 90% of CPU!

If I go to Panel Preferences -> Appearance -> and change Background Style from 'None' (use system style), to 'something else' the the CPU usage reduces to normal.

I have modded the vimix theme it can be found: [Here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1276216/)

This theme also wastes > 90% of CPU, what is causing it? How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what is causing the bug (not familiar with any of these), but the vimix theme page has some comments reporting the issue. https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1276216/

The vimix author says they will fix this in an upcoming update. Perhaps he's looking into what caused the problem. Alternatively, the description mentions the workaround for the problem.
If it turns out to be a bug within an xfce component, it has to be reported as such to the xfce team.

Comment: Yes, that's right, he's fixed the issue. The problem was with the whiskermenu applet! Reducing the button animation time solves the issue, but I haven't yet modded my theme just because it breaks the theme. So I suggest all to just not to use the `None (use system style)` to the panel. That really fixes the problem! Yes, I am using my theme for months without any problem!

Comment: @15Volts Thank god! That solved my issue as well regarding xfce4-panel. Right click on the panel -> Panel -> Panel Preferences -> Appearance tab -> Background style: solid color... Still not fixed in 2023.